# Is there any differnce between buffer and console to make use....

Tags: java

what is the difference when I use buffer istead of console() for retriving the output from my code?

Comment: Sorry but... i was asking about the scanner.nextLine instead of System.console()....

Comment: and which buffer are you talking about

Comment: @Vinit - Edit your question to reflect your requirement correctly. Are you trying to compare `BufferedReader` and `Scanner`?

Comment: Ummm ... sometimes I wish there were more people willing to support  "StackOverflow in <language>" proposals.

Comment: (E.g. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36546/stack-overflow-in-hindi)

Comment: @StephenC: lol when I saw your comment I thought you meant something like *StackOverflow in C#* or whatever. xD

Answer (score 1):

The [`Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class, as used by [`System.console()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29) seems targeted to *interactive* character-based I/O, as provided by an actual console such as a `cmd.exe` window in Windows or a terminal in Unix-like systems. As such, the system console may not always be available, depending on the underlying OS and how the JVM was started.

On the other hand, [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) works with any input stream, including files and the standard input. It is more flexible, but it does not provide some console-specific functionality that `Console` does, such as the ability to read text - usually passwords - without echoing it back to the console.

Answer (score 0):

The `Console` class makes it easy to accept input from the command line, both echoed and unechoed. Unechoed means you will see some special character in your console while writing a text (ex. *, ? etc) like when you enter your password in facebook. :) Its `format()` method also makes it easy to write formatted output to the command line(like making a pyramid of *s or a formatted date and currency formats etc). It also helps to write test engines for unit testing. or you can use it to provide you a simple CLI (Command Line Interface) instead of a GUI (Graphical User Interface) in case you want to create a real simple and small application. And yes, it is also system dependent that means that you cannot always rely on your system to provide you a console instance.

Now about buffering, its actually a technique used in I/O (i.e. both input and output) when you are interacting with a stream (be it a character stream or byte stream, be it from a console or a socket or a file). Its basically used to speed up the I/O and save system resources by avoiding multiple call to `read()` and `write()` methods. It is suggested that you use it in almost every kind of I/O interaction.